# ngrx: how to subscribe the change of a field in state

Tags: angular, ngrx

I am new to ngrx and what to ask, with ngrx, is there any way to subscribe the change of one field in state.

Suppose I have state as

```
export interface AppState {
    fieldA: boolean;
    fieldB: string;
};
```

Now in a component if I have

```
this.appState$ = store.select('appState');
this.appState$.subscribe((state) => {
    this.fieldA= state.fieldA;
});
```

Then even fieldB is changed, the subscription will be triggered as well. Although I can filter it by checking whether or not fieldA is changed or not, is there build-in function in ngrx so that I can only subscribe the change of fieldA.

I tried

```
store.select(s => s.fieldA).subscribe((fieldA) => {
    this.fieldA= fieldA;
});
```

But even fieldA is changed, seems like this subscription is not triggered.

Thanks.

Comment: so you want to subscribe only when filedA changes? no when fieldB? is that correct?

Comment: yes, this is correct. But I want to have fieldA and fieldB in state so that in another component, I can subscribe the change of fieldB only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should

```
store.select('fieldA').subscribe((fieldA) => {
    this.fieldA= fieldA;
});
```

Or, if you want to go deeper, you should pay attention to [selectors](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/docs/store/selectors.md).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tested it but seems like not working.

Comment: @Ben, also you can try `store.select('appState').pipe(pluck('fieldA'))`

Comment: Thanks sychd, `store.select('appState').pipe(pluck('fieldA'))` works great. PS: need to `import { pluck } from 'rxjs/operators';` to use pluck

Comment: FYI pluck is now deprecated https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/pluck